# How to use dropdown as suffix in textfield in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use dropdown at the end of textfield as its part. Like shown in the below image

[image]

I tried the below code

```
TextField(
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {value = it},
            suffix = {
                Row {
                    Text(text = "Select Option")
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = null)
                }
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use text field with dropdown options then may be you should do it in recommended way.

Here, I will provide example which I have worked with, with editable dropdown. However, you can have non-editable too i.e. fixed value from the pre-defined options.

```
@Composable
fun MyDropDownMenuWithTextField(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
val options = listOf<String>("Item 1", "Item2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5")
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = it },
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(), // this modifier brings correctness
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = { selectedOptionText = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Select or write") },
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()
        )
        // filter options based on text field value
        val filteringOptions = options.filter { it.contains(selectedOptionText, ignoreCase = true) }

        if (filteringOptions.isNotEmpty()) {
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
                filteringOptions.forEach { selectionOption ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = selectionOption) },
                        onClick = {
                            selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                            expanded = false
                        },
                        contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i'm trying to add dropdown as part of textfiedl at the end not the the whole dropdown itself. For example in text field user can add name and the drop down attached to it have gender option to select one.